# Always get printed value of "None"

Tags: python

Alright so here is my code, I get the result I want but I keep getting the "None" value under it. How do I eliminate the "None" value?

```
n = input("What day of the week are you leaving?")
r = input("How many days will you be resting?") 

def days(n):
    if n == 0:
        print "Sunday"
    elif n == 1:
        print "Monday"
    elif n == 2:
        print "Tuesday"
    elif n == 3:
        print "Wednesday"
    elif n == 4:
        print "Thrusday"
    elif n == 5:
        print "Friday"
    elif n == 6:
        print "Saturday"
    elif n >= 7:
        print days(n%7)



print days(n+r)
```

Comment: `def days(n): return calendar.day_name[(n + 1) % 7]`. Apart from being shorter it will also give you the correct spelling of "Thursday".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`days` never returns anything, so it implicitly returns `None`. Change all of the `print` statements in `days` to `return` statements:

```
def days(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "Sunday"
    elif n == 1:
        return "Monday"
    elif n == 2:
        return "Tuesday"
    elif n == 3:
        return "Wednesday"
    elif n == 4:
        return "Thrusday"
    elif n == 5:
        return "Friday"
    elif n == 6:
        return "Saturday"
    elif n >= 7:
        return days(n % 7)
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
print days[(n+r) % 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all the `print` statements in your `days(n)` function to `return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You print in function days and print result from function days.
Because of function days returns nothing it prints None.